# Scala throw exception for reading null bigdecimal from query result

Tags: scala, resultset, bigdecimal

I have a method with a body like this:

```
try {
  val query = "SELECT decimalValue as decimal_value FROM table";

  val con = new DbConnection
  val statement = con.preparedStatement(query)

  val rset = statement.executeQuery()

  var myDecimalValue = 0
  if (rset.next()) {
     myDecimalValue = rset.getBigDecimal("decimal_value")
  }
}
catch {
  case e: Exception => println(e.getMessage)
}
```

If the query result is null, I get an exception: `null value for BigDecimal`

but, from `getBigDecimal` method of `ResultSet.java` I found this definition:

```
* @return the column value (full precision);
* if the value is SQL <code>NULL</code>, the value returned is
* <code>null</code> in the Java programming language.
```

How can avoid this? I really need to declare my parameter as Option like this (below), if I know the result can contains null values?!:

```
var myDecimalValue: Option[BigDecimal] = Option(BigDecimal(0))
```

and inside if:

```
val rsetValue = rset.getBigDecimal("decimal_value")
if (rsetValue != null) myDecimalValue = Option(rsetValue)
```

update: stracktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null value for BigDecimal
        at scala.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.scala:405)
        at scala.math.BigDecimal$.apply(BigDecimal.scala:333)
        at scala.math.BigDecimal$.apply(BigDecimal.scala:330)
        at scala.math.BigDecimal$.javaBigDecimal2bigDecimal(BigDecimal.scala:345)
        at ...
        at ...
        at ...
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Did you try to type the variable `myDecimalValue`? Because `myDecimalValue = 0` will not make it a `BigDecimal`. That could be where your exception comes from.

Comment: Idiomatic way would be `val myDecimalValue = if (rset.next) Option(rset.getBigDecimal("decimal_value")) else None`. No null leaks into Scala, no need for a `var`.

Comment: updated with stacktrace. yes, you're right ... I can not avoid using "if condition" inside reading ResultSet. Please make your comment an answer to accept it as solution. I see getDouble can convert a null result directly in 0, maybe this can be a good choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't want to have `null` leaking into Scala code. When interfacing with Java code that can return `null` the best way is to wrap the result into `Option(x)`. That will take care of turning `null` into `None`.

Also avoid `var`, prefer `val`.

So the immediate fix to your program would be

```
val myDecimalValue = if (rs.next) Option(rs.getBigDecimal("decimal_value")) else None
```

---

But what I would also do beyond that is find a reasonable database access library. The full-on Scala solutions like Slick or Doobie are probably a bit challenging for beginners, but raw JDBC is just too painful. Maybe something like Apache DbUtils? No one should need to manually iterate over result sets and pull out columns into variables. You should be getting back Lists of model classes from that library.

Comment: I used Slick, but because it have some incompatibilities with Impala Kudu (don't updates everytime the data or something like that, I use it now just for get data), I rennounced at it and writed plain sql. Anyway, the queries are quite complex and would be more difficult to write them using Slick.